# Certify Compliance - facebook Marketing API

Tags: facebook-marketing-api

We use the Facebook Marketing API to Place Ads. Sometimes when we place Ads on a new account they are not approved and Facebook wants us to Certify Compliance. Please see the attached screen for more details.

Is there any way to certify compliance using an API?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

No, you will need to manually accept the condtions. 
You can only read whether the TOS have been accepted or not.
using the "**tos_accepted**" field in the adaccount request.
Other types of TOS are

- tos_accepted
- user_tos_accepted
- customaudiencestos
- direct_deals_tos_accepted
- offsite_pixels_tos_accepted